# how does the python code df['A'][df['B']] work when the column 'A' is a list of numbers and column 'B' is the target variable?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to run a shapiro test:

```
stats.shapiro(dataframe_iris_new['sepalWidth'][dataframe_iris_new['target']])
```

I am confused with how the above code works.

Answer (score 0):

When you do dataframe['columnA'] it will return only that column, so it should throw error. Can you paste the output here?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Series like this:

```
> s = pd.Series({
    2: 'Alan',
    4: 'Mary',
    6: 'Sophie',
    8: 'Jack'
})

2      Alan
4      Mary
6    Sophie
8      Jack
dtype: object
```

You can slice it by a single *label* or a *list of labels*:

```
> s[[2]]

2    Alan
dtype: object

> s[[6,2]]

6    Sophie
2      Alan
```

You can also slice with it a boolean list:

```
> s[[False, True, True, False]]

4      Mary
6    Sophie
dtype: object
```

So how does this fit into your question?

- `dataframe_iris_new['sepalWidth']` returns a series (let's call it `s`)
- `dataframe_iris_new['target']` reutns another series (let's call it `t`)

`s[t]` is a slicing operation: cutting `s` according to the values in `t`:

- If `t` is a list of labels, it will extract matching labels in `s`
- If `t` is a boolean list, it will select the items where the value of `t` is True. This also requires that `s` and `t` are of the same length.